# How to get class information using dwarf information from Linux Executables?

Tags: linux, gdb, elf, dwarf

Basically, How to list down all the class information using Dwarf information from Linux Executable.

For Example : If a c++ project compile with debug symbol, and we have only Linux Executable with Debug Information than how we can print the the class information ?

```
e.g
class a :
{
 public:
    ----
    ----

 private:
     ----
     ----
};
```

Comment: Does this do what you want? `gdb -batch -ex "ptype a" ./executable`

Comment: Try using dwarfdump to dump all attributes and see DW_TAG_class_type to reverse engineering what you want manually first.